# Tornado static files serving url configuration

Tags: python, tornado

I configured torando for serving static files for development purposes.

```
            settings = {
                    'template_path': 'templates',
                    'static_path': 'static'
            }
```

Inside my template files I am using static_url() to give proper path to my static files.

Because my html files have structure of static files already defined tornado static_url isn't showing correct path.

For example, on my server file is having url like

```
<link href="/myflz/resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

and after using static_url it is

```
<link href="/static/myflz/resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

How can I get rid of static before myflz because changing 'static_path': 'static' to 'static_path': 'myflz' doesn't work, it still uses static in front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `static_url_prefix` (which replaces `/static/` at the front of the url) instead of `static_path` (which is the location on disk where the static files are stored).